# Changes to /etc/bashrc?

Tags: bash, bashrc

Are there any changes you make to the default bash reconfiguration script that would be helpful for others to know?

Note that /etc/bashrc affects all users, where a .bashrc in a user's home directory just affects that user.

Comment: Pretty much a dupe of http://serverfault.com/questions/3743/what-useful-things-can-one-add-to-ones-bashrc
Only difference is user vs global changes.

Comment: Right, I want to know what things are good for _all_ users to have.

Comment: Ok then, so its related, not a dupe :-)

Could you not pick related records from the above URL however.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't change the default `/etc/bashrc`.  Instead, I would create a new file in

```
/etc/profile.d/
```

This way you have something that will survive upgrades.  At least in Fedora and earlier RedHat, the `/etc/bashrc` contains the following bit of script:

```
for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r "$i" ]; then
        . $i
fi
```

The last time I wanted to add something globally, I created a new file in this directory with a name ending in `.sh` and a `csh` version ending in `.csh`.

Answer (score 3):

For reference the default Debian bashrc is stored in /etc/bash.bashrc rather than /etc/bashrc.

Comment: This applies to Arch Linux as well.

Answer (score 1):

The /etc/bashrc of most distributions are pretty small and readable. I suggest reading them. If someone could find links to all the major ones, I would vote that up multiple times if I could.