# Useful bash aliases and generating a listing of your most used commands

Tags: bash, alias

I found [this](http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2007/01/whats_in_your_bash_history.html) article discussing a quick way to sort your bash history and see which commands you use the most:

```
cut -f1 -d" " .bash_history | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 30
```

It really opens your eyes as to which tasks you should create aliases for and which ones you should cronjob away completely.

**I'd love to see a ServerFault list of recommended command line aliases that save you time on the job**. What have you got?

Between us, I'll bet we can save every user who reads this post at least 10 minutes a day. (Minus the first day wherein they waste all of their time reading ServerFault instead of doing their job of course!)

Comment: For the record, on Super User there's http://superuser.com/questions/7083/useful-command-line-aliases with loads of useful Bash aliases

Comment: See also: http://serverfault.com/questions/15365/favorite-unix-command-line-aliases

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I deal with a lot of different machines so one of my favorites is aliases for each machine that I need to frequently SSH to:

```
alias claudius="ssh dinomite@claudius"
```

It is also useful to setup a good [`.ssh/config`](http://kimmo.suominen.com/docs/ssh/) and [ssh keys](http://pkeck.myweb.uga.edu/ssh/) to make hopping amongst machines even easier.

Another one of my favorite aliases is for moving up directories:

```
alias ..="cd .."
alias ...="cd ../.."
alias ....="cd ../../.."
alias .....="cd ../../../.."
```

And some for commonly used variations of `ls` (and typos):

```
alias ll="ls -l"
alias lo="ls -o"alias lh="ls -lh"
alias la="ls -la"
alias sl="ls"
alias l="ls"
alias s="ls"
```

I almost always want `egrep`:

```
alias grep="egrep"
```

Get man pages from all sections

```
alias man="man -a"
```

I often found myself piping output through `awk` in order to get a certain column of the output, as in `df -h | awk '{print $2}'` to find the size of each of my disks.  To make this easier, I created a function `fawk` in my .bashrc:

```
function fawk {
    first="awk '{print "
    last="}'"
    cmd="${first}\$${1}${last}"
    eval $cmd
}
```

I can now run `df -h|fawk 2` which saves a good bit of typing.

I work with a lot of Perl and need to know the versions of modules installed on a system:

```
function perlmodver {
    perl -M$1 -e 'print "Version " .
        $ARGV[0]->VERSION . " of " . $ARGV[0] .
        " is installed.\n"' $1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I usually like to type everything, because I'm afraid I'll forget all about the commands I'm using in no time. I know I may be wrong, but I don't think I'd know as much about the system if I had just pasted every command in [Commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/browse) into my .bashrc.

Note that I'm not saying that I'm the greatest and I know everything there is to know about Linux, far from that, I'm just saying I like to learn, and remember what I've learned by using.

That's not to say I don't appreciate how time saving aliases are (specially for larger functions, but then you have to see if a script isn't better), but, personally, I don't like to use them (at least no always).

That being said, Commandlinefu has a special [tag](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/tagged/126/alias) for aliases. It's worth looking.

Also I think this is a good one:

```
   alias less='less -FSRX'
```

This will only use less if the output is bigger than the screen.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite of all times:

```
alias server_name='ssh -v -l username ip_address'
```

It doesn't need explanation, does it? :-)

Comment: Isn't that what's .ssh/config is for :-P 
Host server_name
Hostname 1.2.3.4
User username
etc.

Comment: Using bash_completion and tab,tab seems to work just fine for me, instead of setting up a bunch of ssh aliases

Answer (score 2):

`alias lt='ls -lhart'`

- l=long : h=human readable sizes : a=all : r=reverse sort : t=time sort
- Puts the newest file at the bottom, right above the prompt

`alias active='grep -v -e "^$" -e"^ *#"'`

- shows only lines that are not blank or commented out
- example: active /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

`alias svi='sudo vim'`

`alias scr='screen -Rd'`

Comment: Nice, especially sudo vim

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit I have a few like this..

```
alias sl=ls
```

To try and combat my typos :-)

I also have

```
alias aliases='xterm -e vim ~/.bash_aliases;reload'
alias reload='. ~/.bash_aliases'
```

So its nice and simple to add new ones.

Answer (score 1):

```
alias cd..='cd ..'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for host in `awk '{ print $1 }' ~/.hostsILogIntoAllTheTime`; do
  alias $host='ssx '$host
done
```

Type the hostname to logon to the host.  Note: ssx is an alias itself:

```
ssx='ssh -Y'
```

Combined with shared keys, it's pretty slick.

Answer (score 1):

I find annoying to put the whole apt-get and apt-cache things in debian / *buntu, especially with sudo prefix, so I have:

```
alias apti='sudo apt-get install'
alias aptr='sudo apt-get remove'
alias apts='apt-cache search'
```

Answer (score 1):

create .tar.gz

```
alias tarc="tar czvf"
```

extract .tar.gz

```
alias tarx="tar xzvf"
```

list .tar.gz

```
alias tart="tar tzvf"
```

Answer (score 0):

Also see

- [What useful things can one add to one's .bashrc?](https://serverfault.com/questions/3743/what-useful-things-can-one-add-to-ones-bashrc)
- [Interactive shell tips?](https://serverfault.com/questions/5027/interactive-shell-tips) (some answers include aliases)

Answer (score 0):

I found this page looking for a way to make an alias to show me the nth column of a csv (tsv actually) file using awk.  The fawk function above was almost exactly what I wanted.  I modified slightly to add an optional second argument, the filename, so I can use it like awk normally rather than only through a pipe.

```
function fawk {
    first="awk '{print "
    last="}' $2"
    cmd="${first}\$${1}${last}"
    echo $cmd
    eval $cmd
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an alias, but seeing people who aliases ssh connections, might be useful.

Openssh package has a binary called ssh-argv0 that works via symlinks.

So, if you do something like this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ssh-argv0 /usr/local/bin/user@ssh.server.com
```

Having /usr/local/bin in the $PATH, now you can connect as user "user" to ssh.server.com writing this in a shell prompt:

```
 $ user@ssh.server.com
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Drew Stephens answer. The only one he didn't cover that I also use is to alias the various dot files I need to access on a regular basis like:

```
alias dotz='vi ~/.zshrc'
```

Take it a step further with an on-the-fly add-alias function:

```
function add-alias {
echo "alias $1=\047$2\047" >> ~/.zshrc
}
```