# Favorite Unix command line aliases?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line-interface

What are your favorite command line aliases (bash/sh/tcsh) aliases?  Here are a few of mine.

```
alias lsr='ls -lrt'
alias gon='cd $HOME/Notes'
alias devdb='mysql -h dev --user=x --password=secret dbname'
alias ec='rm *~'; # emacs cleanup
alias h='history'
alias eb='exec bash'; # Solaris sometimes defaults to sh
alias mr='more'
alias mroe='more'
alias qd='echo export DISPLAY=$DISPLAY'
alias ralias='. $HOME/.alias'; # reread aliases
alias ,,='cd ../..'
alias ..='cd ..'
alias c='clear'
```

Comment: Rather than passing your password in on the commandline to `mysql` (anyone else on the server could see it!), put the username and password in a ~/.my.cnf file, and simply specify `-up`. MySQL tools will pick those credentials up automatically, read mysql(1) for more info.

Comment: +1 For *alias ..='cd ..'*

Comment: +1 for 'mroe'.  I need to take care of my common misspellings...

Answer (score 12):

```
function s()
{
    screen -t "$@" /usr/bin/ssh "$@"
}
```

Connect to a host in a new screen tab, with the device name as the tab title.

Answer (score 11):

My favourites that haven't been mentioned so far:

```
alias l='ls'
alias u='cd ..'
alias uu='cd ../..'
alias uuu='cd ../../..'
alias uuuu='cd ../../../..'
```

I'm not normally a fan of aliases that just shorten things, but I type ls so very much, and l only needs one hand.

Comment: ls (and cd) only needs one hand...if the keymap is Dvorak!  Same hand as 'Enter', for that matter.

Answer (score 8):

none since I can never guarantee they'll be configured on EVERY system I'll log into (as myself, root, or whoever).

Comment: Exactly! Harmless things like 
alias ls="ls --color=auto
are fine, but changing the rm command etc.? Never.

Answer (score 7):

None, I change between systems so much every day that I basically gave up on it.

Comment: You don't sync your home directories between the various machines?

http://xoa.petdance.com/How_to:_Keep_your_home_directory_in_Subversion

Comment: I maintain with a group of other administrators around 5k machines, most of these machines during their entire lifespan never had an remote interactive user session (all installation and configuration happens automatically), sometimes there is a wierd problem and you do have to log on. We have considered to have the user admins account to auto mount from a shared NFS partition, but for the use of it isn't worth it.

Comment: ...don't have admin/root accounts include nfs directories in its path -- when NFS is bork, so is admin/root accounts.  Some of my clients insist on learning this the hard way.

Answer (score 7):

```
alias ..="cd .."
alias ...="cd ../.."

# mkdir and enter it immediately thereafter
mcd()           { mkdir $1 && cd $1; }

# when entering a directory, list the contents.
cd()            { builtin cd "$@" && ls; }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
alias rm 'mv -f \!* $WASTEBASKET'
alias unrm 'mv $WASTEBASKET/\!* .'
```

I know that many will disagree, but I *like* safety nets. (And please try to forgive me for using tcsh.)

This somewhat similar one should be outlawed, though:

```
alias rm 'rm -i'
```

I've seen people who were trained on systems with that alias, and then they type `rm *` on some other system, expecting to get questions about which files to delete, and then they sit there and watch it do exactly what it is supposed to do.

EDIT:

Some of the comments compared the move-to-wastebasket alias with the "-i" flag, saying that they are similar. But to me, there is an important difference. With "-i", you get the confirmation prompt every time you use the command, and it becomes something you expect and rely on. The wastebasket solution, on the other hand, works exactly like the standard rm,  until you actually make a mistake and need to un-remove a file. It's a bit like the difference between training wheels and a spare tire in the trunk.

Comment: the bash equivalent requires a function: del() { path=`readlink -f "$1"` mkdir -p $WASTE$path mv $path $WASTE$path } Its not perfect (as it creates a new dir with the filename) but it works ok. (putting in newlines is left as exercise for reader!)

Comment: +1: I use Tcsh too :-)

Comment: +1: you're forgiven for using tcsh ;)

Comment: Well in fairness, expecting a confirmation prompt and not getting one is just as bad as expecting it to go into a wastebasket and that not happening. There's no difference, really.

Comment: @Dan: I thought the same. The alias really should not be called rm, but wb for wastebasket, or something similar.

Comment: On of my company's "shared" machines we have this:

    % which rm
    rm:      aliased to echo Remove !* \?\?\?

If you are really sure about deleting type /bin/rm
I'm not sure how good it is for preventing real accidents though.

Answer (score 6):

The total contents of my "alias list" is:

I've spent enough time fixing unix machines I don't "normally" work with (one of the downsides of having been in-house unix admin for a software house, you end up on customer sites, A Lot) that the first thing I do is to "unalias -a", just so that any alias the normal production admin have don't happen to interact with a mis-spelling, after that it's too much hassle to customise.

This has carried over into my normal usage, too.

Answer (score 4):

These are for zsh, but I imagine you could port them to another shell reasonably easily:

```
sudo() { [[ $1 == (vi|vim) ]] && shift && sudoedit "$@" || command sudo "$@"; } # sudo vi/vim => sudoedit
wst() { TZ=Australia/Perth date } # get local time no matter what server I'm on

FULLHOST=`hostname -f` 2>/dev/null || FULLHOST=`hostname` # reasonably portable, always gets a DHCP suffix too (if one exists)
SHORTHOST=`echo $FULLHOST | cut -d. -f1-2` # get the first two segments of hostname, which I used in my shell prompt
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, what is the difference between sudo vim and sudoedit? Is sudo edit = sudo $EDITOR ?

Comment: sudoedit runs your editor under your account, rather than as root. That means you get access to your own ~/.vimrc and so on.

Comment: +1 for changing `sudo vi <somefile>` to `sudoedit <somefile`! +more if I could

Answer (score 4):

Here are some of my favorites.  (A few are ZSH-specific.)

```
alias ls='ls -F --color=auto'
alias l='ls'
alias ll='ls -ahl'
alias ..='cd ..'
alias ...='cd ../..'
alias mv='mv -i'
alias mmv='noglob zmv -W'
alias mcp='mmv -C'

mkcd() {
        if [ $1 = "" ]; then
                echo "Usage: mkcd <dir>"
        else
                mkdir -p $1
                cd $1
        fi
}

# ZSH global aliases for piping
alias -g H="| head"
alias -g T="| tail"
alias -g C="| wc -l"
alias -g L="| less"
alias -g G="| grep"
alias -g S="| sed -e"
alias -g A="| awk"

# Subversion related
alias ss='svn status'
alias sd='svn diff'
alias sc='svn commit'

# Git related
alias gs='git status'
alias gc='git commit'
alias ga='git add'
alias gd='git diff'
alias gb='git branch'
alias gl='git log'
alias gsb='git show-branch'
alias gco='git checkout'
alias gg='git grep'
alias gk='gitk --all'
alias gr='git rebase'
alias gri='git rebase --interactive'
alias gcp='git cherry-pick'
alias grm='git rm'

fortune -s  # Add to your profile to brighten your day :)
```

Answer (score 4):

For those troublesome colleagues:

```
alias ls=rm
```

Comment: I prefer the much more subtle "alias vi=vi -R"

Answer (score 4):

there are many aliases here wich are not neccessary:

```
alias c='clear'
```

can be replaced by just pressing [Ctrl]+[L]

```
alias mroe='more'
```

and similar: zsh provides spell correction by default, bash does it with extensions

```
alias something="history | grep $@"
```

pressing [Ctrl]+[R] does the same thing in bash/zsh

```
back='cd $OLDPWD'
```

the same can be done in every shell with

```
cd -
```

Answer (score 3):

```
jldugger@jldugger:~ $ alias 
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias youtube-dl='youtube-dl -t
```

Answer (score 3):

```
alias perg='grep -rni --exclude=\*.svn\*'
alias df='df -kTh'
alias ll="ls -l --group-directories-first"
```

Comment: For the first one try "ack". it is a programmer's grep ;) http://betterthangrep.com/

Answer (score 3):

```
alias cdd='cd /wherever/my/current/project/is'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
alias ls="ls --color=auto -A -h -i -s --group-directories-first -l"
alias screen="screen -U"
alias sscreen="~/Projects/bin/start_screen.sh"
alias gst='git status'
alias gl='git pull'
alias gp='git push'
alias gd='git diff | emacs'
alias gc='git commit -v'
alias gca='git commit -v -a'
alias gb='git branch'
alias gba='git branch -a'
```

Answer (score 2):

p='ps auxww|grep -v grep|grep '

Comment: In some cases, pgrep is useful. Not the same effect, but still useful.

Answer (score 2):

For searching old perl scripts for something:

```
alias searchperl 'find /place1 /place2 /place3 -name "*.pl" | xargs grep
```

Email myself a file:

```
alias mailthis 'mail -s mailthis email@email.com < '
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ "$(uname)"="darwin" ]; then
  EDITOR=mate
  PATH=$PATH:~/.bin
  alias sleep_hdd='sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 1'
  alias sleep_ram='sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 0'
  alias sleep_combined='sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 3'
  alias cdproj='cd ~/Projects/Web'
  alias e='mate'
  alias vboxheadless='VBoxHeadless -startvm '
  alias subash='sudo bash'
fi

if [ "$(uname)" = "SunOS" ]; then
  alias ls='ls -F'
  alias e='vim'
  alias subash='pfexec bash'
fi
```

Comment: vboxheadless should already be in your $PATH:
uname; which vboxheadless
Darwin
/usr/bin/vboxheadless

Answer (score 1):

```
alias l='ls --color=auto -lsah'
alias ..='cd ..'
```

I miss it very often on other systems

Answer (score 1):

This one works on most linux desktops:

```
alias go='xdg-open'
```

Opens a document or folder with the registered application, similar to the start command on windows.

Comment: Change it to xdg-open and it should work on any XDG-compliant desktop environment.

Answer (score 1):

```
history | awk '{print $2}' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|"} {print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -10
```

Show the top 10 most used commands in your history.

Comment: shorter version, no need for awk:
history | cut -f 5 -d' ' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail

Answer (score 1):

```
alias viewpw='aespipe -d < ~/.passwd.aes > ~/.passwd.dec && more ~/.passwd.dec && shred -u ~/.passwd.dec'
```

How I remember all my passwords...

Answer (score 1):

Here is my favorite, to find something in all of the Python code in the current and child directories, excluding those associated with subversion:

`alias greppy="find . | grep -v [.]svn | grep [.]py$ | xargs grep "`

Answer (score 1):

A few plucked from my bashrc:

```
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias egrep='grep -E --color=auto'
alias e='$EDITOR'
alias g='git'
alias csort='sort | uniq -c | sort -n' # column sort piped data
alias sl='ls' # fat fingers
```

Generally, I usually have my bashrc figure out what package manager the system uses and then have it aliased as `apt` and `yum`, meaning on any machine on which my bashrc runs, I can just do:

```
apt search foo
yum install foo
apt update
```

It's not perfect but most of the common actions are the same between yum and aptitude, by the time you're trying to do something more complicated you can just remember what OS you're on.

Answer (score 1):

Probably my favorite, since it makes writing new aliases so easy:

```
alias realias='vim ~/.bash_aliases;source ~/.bash_aliases'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is my favorite alias.

alias resume='screen -D -R'

It proves to be very handy after my windows workstation is automatically rebooted every weekend (Firm's policy).

Answer (score 1):

A few more to add to the pile:

```
# little bit more readable PATH
alias path='echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n}'

# like others, I find these more efficient than
# typing cd ../../ etc
alias up='cd ..'
alias 2up='cd ../../'
alias 3up='cd ../../../'
alias 4up='cd ../../../../'

# found myself always mistyping this, so...
alias findy='find . -name'


alias targz='tar -xzvf'
alias hg='history | grep '
alias cls='clear'

# handy for the xclip tool
alias xclip='xclip -selection c'

# quick directory listing
alias ldir='ls -d */'

alias mys='mysql -uroot -psecret name-of-frequently-used-DB' 

alias trash='mv -t ~/.local/share/Trash/files --backup=t'
alias vb='vim ~/.bashrc'
alias +='pushd .'
alias _='popd'
```

Comment: Storing passwords in scripts like this is potentially dangerous, unless you got it 600.  Also upon execution your password goes to history file--also potentially dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

```
alias dsclean='find . -name .DS_Store -exec rm \{\} \;'
alias l='ls -lh'
alias ls='ls -G'

# Depends on your specific router
alias myip='curl -sn http://192.168.1.1/wancfg.cmd?action=view | grep td | tail -1 | tr -d '\''/<>a-z '\'''

# Start/stop local mysql installation
alias myserver='sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server'
alias rssh='ssh -l root'
alias sc='./script/console'
alias sr='screen -r'
alias ss='./script/server'
alias sss='screen ./script/server'
alias up='svn up'
alias webshare='python -c "import SimpleHTTPServer;SimpleHTTPServer.test()"'
```

Answer (score 1):

Do quick arithmetic from the command line. Use "x" for multiplication to avoid expansion.

```
function math
{       
    echo "scale=2 ; $*" | sed -e "s:x:*:g" | sed -e "s:,::g" | bc
}


$ math 12,537.2 x 4
50148.8
```

Answer (score 1):

[Unix alias command with examples](http://scripterworld.blogspot.com/2009/09/unix-alias-command-parameters-or.html)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
back='cd $OLDPWD'
```

I really hate typing that '$' ...

Answer (score 1):

Two more complicated shell functions. I use them often when searching stuff in source code or config files.

```
FFind() {
    if [ -n "$1" ] ; then
        if [ -n "$2" ] ; then
            local testVar="$1"
            shift
            find . -type f \
                -and '(' -not -path '*.git*' ')' \
                -and '(' -not -path '*.svn*' ')' \
                -and '(' -not -path '*.hg*' ')' \
                -and '(' "$@" ')' \
                -exec grep --color=always -I -i -F -H -n "${testVar}" {} ';'
        else 
            find . -type f \
                -and '(' -not -path '*.git*' ')' \
                -and '(' -not -path '*.svn*' ')' \
                -and '(' -not -path '*.hg*' ')' \
                -exec grep --color=always -I -i -F -H -n "$1" {} ';'
        fi
    fi
}

EFind() {
    if [ -n "$1" ] ; then
        if [ -n "$2" ] ; then
            local testVar="$1"
            shift
            find . -type f \
                -and '(' -not -path '*.git*' ')' \
                -and '(' -not -path '*.svn*' ')' \
                -and '(' -not -path '*.hg*' ')' \
                -and '(' "$@" ')' \
                -exec grep --color=always -I -i -E -H -n -m 1 "${testVar}" {} ';'
        else 
            find . -type f \
                -and '(' -not -path '*.git*' ')' \
                -and '(' -not -path '*.svn*' ')' \
                -and '(' -not -path '*.hg*' ')' \
                -exec grep --color=always -I -i -E -H -n -m 1 "$1" {} ';'
        fi
    fi
}
```

Usage:

```
FFind elephant
```

Recursively searches all text files in the current directory for the string elehant. Ignores files created by Subverion, git or mercurial. Ignores binary files.

```
FFind 'ele.*phant' -name '*.c' -or -name '*.h'
```

Recursively searches all c code files in the current directory for the string 'ele.*hant' (no regular expression matching). Ignores files created by Subverion, git or mercurial.

```
EFind 'mo*use' -name '*.java'
```

Recursively searches all java code files in the current directory for the string muse or mouse or moouse or .... Ignores files created by Subverion, git or mercurial.

Tested with bash and zsh.

Comment: How's this differ from ack? http://betterthangrep.com/

Comment: i didnt know of ack till now. Ill give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Some of my best collection :)

```
alias cdd="cd .."  
alias lss="ls -ctrl"  
alias nn="nautilus . &"  
alias pp="popd"  
alias p="pushd"  
alias g="gvim --servername `hostname` --remote"
alias findd="find . -name"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alias t="rlog -L -l -R RCS/*"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#. Darwin:
.  : source
ls : ls -G -F
resize : osascript << EOF
  tell app "Terminal"
    set number of rows of first window to 25
    set number of columns of first window to 80
    set custom title of first window to "${PROFILE}"
  end tell
EOF

#. Linux:
.  : source
ls : ls --color=auto -F -X -h
```

...in general - I don't like using aliases too much though, you become dependent and learn to use something which only ever exists if you yourself make it so.  I'd then feel handicapped when jumping on someone else's machine, even for a minute - so my general advice would be to use aliases very lightly.

For example aliasing `ls` to `ls -F` is ok, because it only has cosmetic effects, but aliasing to it `ls -l` or something - I would never do.  I don't like these `ll for ls -l` aliases either for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

We tend to use rdp a bit, because we can only access certain servcices via windows so I like:

`alias rdt='rdesktop -d UOFA  -g 1024x768 -u '`

usage is

`rdt <win_username> <winhost>`

A lot of our stuff is in LDAP so search as the directory manager is useful (with an apporpirately configured `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf`):

`alias dmsearch='ldapsearch -x -LLL -D"<directory_admin_bind_dn>" -W '`

`alias budate='date +%Y%m%d-%H%M'` E.g. `cp -p some-conf.comf someconf-'budate'.conf` NB repalce the single quotes with backticks. Serverfault wont let me put in backtick literals and I cant work out how to escape backticks.

`alias psg='ps aux|grep '`

Answer (score 0):

Not an alias but a function, since i hate manually checking of the sshd is up after a reboot I have a waiting-for-ssh-to-answer function in my .zshrc:

```
function wssh () {
local HOST=$1
shift
local PORT=$1
if [[ -z $PORT ]]; then
        PORT=22
else
        shift
fi
echo -n "Polling host $HOST on port $PORT for ssh connection"
while ! nc -z -w 2 $HOST $PORT &>/dev/null; do
        for i in `jot 2 1`; do
                echo -n "."
                sleep 2
        done
done
echo "\nConnection establihed!"
ssh -p$PORT $HOST $@
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alias uab='unison -rsync -auto -batch'
```

I use [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) to sync my settings, read/undread newsgroup mesages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
alias memusage='ps -o rss,command -waxc | sort -n'
alias ssq='svn status -q'
alias up='cd ..'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alias svndiff='svn diff --diff-cmd=colordiff'
alias df='df -h'
```

The first line uses colordiff to colorize svn diff output

Answer (score 0):

Most of our servers don't listen to SSH on a public VLAN. I can't be bothered to keep a tunnel open on my laptop when away from the office:

```
zugzug() { ssh -A -p <non_standard_port> -t <proxy_server> ssh $1; }
```

While it's a function and not an alias, I find it invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

a few choice LAMP related snippets:

apache: current activity

```
alias apache_status='watch -n1 "/etc/init.d/httpd fullstatus | egrep \"GET|POST\""'
```

apache: check config and gracefully restart if all ok

```
alias graceful='/etc/init.d/httpd configtest && /etc/init.d/httpd graceful && echo Gracefully Done'
```

get process info

```
alias pinfo='/root/procinfo'
```

redhat release info

```
alias about='cat /etc/redhat-release && cat /proc/version && uname -a' alias
```

start vim in insert mode (contraversial!)

```
alias vi='vim -c startinsert'
```

monitor drbd activity and state of bonded NICs

```
alias cluster='watch -d -n0.2 cat /proc/drbd /proc/net/bonding/bond0'
```

Answer (score 0):

to display squid log file in real time

alias proxy='tail -f /usr/local/squid/var/logs/access.log'

Answer (score 0):

[Some more information about Unix alias command](http://scripterworld.blogspot.com/2009/09/unix-alias-command-parameters-or.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
    alias pd=pushd
    alias so="echo ^O"
    alias sy='rsync -vaH'
    alias tcem='echo -ne "\033[?25h"'
    alias tt='traceroute -I'
    alias x=type
```

Answer (score 0):

**List all the files in this directory, and sort by human-readable file size.**

```
alias sizes="du --max-depth=1 -k | sort -nr | cut -f2 | xargs -d '\n' du -sh"
```

I use it a lot on some servers with very limited disk space.

Answer (score 0):

To add up a column of numbers, I have this in my .bashrc.  If you give it a filename as a 2nd arugment, it will sum up the passed-in column number of that file instead of std-in.

```
sumcol() {
   awk "BEGIN { SUM=0 } { SUM+=\$$1 } END { print SUM }" $2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got many aliases, I copied this one from somewhere.

```
alias dirf='find . -type d | sed -e "s/[^-][^\/]*\//  |/g" -e "s/|\([^ ]\)/|-\1/"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also:

```
alias dmeasg='dmesg'
```

I typed it so often wrong, that I made an alias for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
alias agc='df -h; apt-get autoclean ; apt-get clean ; apt-get autoremove ; df -h'
alias agi='apt-get install '
alias acs='apt-cache search '
alias agdu='apt-get update ; apt-get dist-upgrade'
```

Answer (score 0):

I may rebuild the same system 5+ times in one day.  This helps speed up removing the entry from known_hosts.

`remove-known-host() {`
`local HOST=$1`

`grep -v $HOST ~/.ssh/known_hosts > ~/.ssh/known_hosts.tmp`
`mv ~/.ssh/known_hosts.tmp ~/.ssh/known_hosts`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

RedHat based systems, e.g. RHEL, CentOS, Fedora come with the following aliases:

```
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias l.='ls -d .* --color=auto'
alias ll='ls -l --color=auto'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias mc='. /usr/libexec/mc/mc-wrapper.sh'
alias vi='vim'
alias which='alias | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde'
```