# Is there a way to push shell config information when SSHing to a host?

Tags: ssh, shell

I've got a [bunch of good stuff](https://serverfault.com/questions/3743/what-useful-things-can-one-add-to-ones-bashrc/5551#5551) in my bash config.  Normally when I get a new account, I pull this down from [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/dinomite/homedir) so that I have all the aliases and features I'm used to.  There are some hosts that I access which I don't have my own accounts on, but shared accounts that a bunch of people use, so it would be rude of me to install my shell config.

Is there a way to push my shell config, or at least some initialization commands, over the SSH session so that I have the environment I'm used to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert obligatory grumble about shared accounts, but if you at least have your own ssh key, you can (ab)use the `command=` option in the [`~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd&sektion=8#AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FILE_FORMAT). A key with a command option is good only for running the specified command; but the command in the authorized_keys file runs with the environment variable `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` set to the command the user specified (empty for interactive sessions). So you can use something like this in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`:

```
command="HOME=$HOME/.HOME.drew;
         if [ -n \"$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND\" ]; then
           eval \"$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND\";
         else exec \"$SHELL\"; fi" ssh-rsa AAAA…== drew@example.com
```

Note that I put line breaks above for legibility, but this actually needs to be all on one line in the `authorized_keys` file.

Then put your favorite configuration files in that `.HOME.drew` directory.

For punctual use, you can explicitly source a profile file or run any shell command. Pass the `-t` option to have a terminal if you want to run interactive commands.

```
ssh shared-account@server "LS_COLORS='$LS_COLORS' ls --color"
ssh -t shared-account@server '. ~/.profile.drew; exec zsh'
```

If you only want to edit or copy files on the remote machine, you can use a network filesystem such as [SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) (for unix clients) or [Tramp](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/) (for Emacs) and work from the comfort of your local environment.

Comment: Oh, I'm totally with you on the grumbling!

Answer (score 1):

I like to keep a file `.bsa` somewhere convenient (maybe `~` will work in this case) so I can just `. ~/.bsa` to get my environment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to hack something together with "LocalCommand" (see man ssh_config)?

Comment: That permits running something on the local machine. How would that help?

Comment: By using that as a trigger to launch a script on the local machine (which seems to be his starting point in each case) that will copy over whatever he needs to the target.